# Menu not showing up after using document click function event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating multiple navigation buttons for my website, each of them would show up menus.

So as example, this is the first menu:

```
<div class="outer-bar">
    <ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
        <li>
            <label id="down-nav-1" class="down-nav" onclick="Dropdown1()">Knives <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
            <div class="mainsizer">
                <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-1">
                    <a href=/?search=M9%20Bayonet&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="m9_bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M9 Bayonet</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Karambit&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="karambit" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:59px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Karambit</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Bayonet&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:116px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bayonet</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Butterfly%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="butterfly" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:170px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Butterfly Knife</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Flip%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="flip" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:225px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Flip Knife</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Falchion%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="falchion" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:280px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Falchion Knife</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Gut%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="gut" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:334.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Gut Knife</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Shadow%20Daggers&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="shadow" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:390px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Shadow Daggers</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Huntsman%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="huntsman" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:444px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Huntsman Knife</a>
                    <a href=/?search=Bowie%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="bowie" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:498.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bowie Knife</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

So as you see on the `<label>` element #down-nav-1, it has `onclick` attribute linked to the function `Dropdown1()` and `Display` of menu is `None` and the time.

And this is the function itself in Javascript:

```
function Dropdown1() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-menu-1").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("down-nav-1").style.cssText = "border: solid 3px gray;background-color: gray;border-radius: 10px;";
}
```

All of this would simply work **fine**, please see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjfz7twq/). (Only "Knives" button works atm).

But then i tried to add a function, so when user clicks outside of the menu, the display would be set to 'None' again:

```
function Dropdown1() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-menu-1").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("down-nav-1").style.cssText = "border: solid 3px gray;background-color: gray;border-radius: 10px;";
}

$(document).click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#dropdown-menu-1').length) {
        if ( ($('#dropdown-menu-1').style.display = "None" ) {
            $('#dropdown-menu-1').style.display = "inline-block";
        }
    }
})
```

And after adding this code, there would be no action when clicking the button. ( [see the result](https://jsfiddle.net/bjfz7twq/1/) ).

---

I don't understand the specific problem in there, but please note, i am new to Javascript, and don't know many things in there.

What could the problem be? can i do this with pure Javascript or should i use jquery in this case?

Comment: Or... just code the damn thing properly, and use only HTML and CSS? There is no need for JS for such a simple thing as this.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I have used checkbox input in past, but apparently pseudo elements do not work with Trident layout engine. ( Internet explorer ).

Comment: Eh, what now? How far back do you need to support?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Well i'm pretty sure there should be solution.

Comment: @ShellRox Can you kindly see my answer?

Comment: Yes sure, i am trying it right now.

Comment: @ShellRox I have also provided a full screen preview... Once you click on the menu, if there are anything else open, that gets closed and then current menu will be opened. If the current menu is open, that's closed. This is the logic I am following, hope that's what you need.

Comment: And... it still uses bloated code, and javascript, for something incredibly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax & logical error in the code.

Updated your code:

```
function Dropdown1() {
  if ($('#dropdown-menu-1').css("display") !== "none") {
      $('#dropdown-menu-1').css("display", "none");
   } else {
      $('#dropdown-menu-1').css("display", "inline-block");
   }
  document.getElementById("down-nav-1").style.cssText = "border: solid 3px gray; background-color: gray; border-radius: 10px;";
}

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.outer-bar').length) {
    if ($('#dropdown-menu-1').css("display") !== "none") {
      $('#dropdown-menu-1').css("display", "none");
    }
  }
});
```

Please use `==` or `===` instead of the `=` operator when comparing inside your `if` blocks.

Also brackets were not closed in the `if` block expressions.

Also, `style.display` is a property associated to a JavaScript object and not a jQuery object. You should use `.css("display")` for a jQuery object.

Updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/bjfz7twq/7/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix, but unfortunately it couldn't solve my problem, when clicking outside menu wouldn't close: https://jsfiddle.net/bjfz7twq/2/

Comment: @ShellRox I have updated my answer to exactly solve your code and your problem (without introducing any new code). This should be the accepted answer here.

Comment: Yes, it almost solved my problem, just there is a little bug, when clicking outside it opens again.

Comment: @ShellRox Updated. This has to work exactly as you want. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have two last questions, How can i also close the menu when clicked to `#down-nav-1`, and would it work on multiple menus? Thanks again, and answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ShellRox Updated your `Dropdown1` function for that. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, please use it consistently. Don't mix both jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript. To do something very simple dropdown like that, you just need to use JavaScript to **only change classes** and not the original effect. All the others should be handled by CSS.

Technically, this is achievable just using HTML and CSS. There are 1000s of examples outside. Also, you should use event handlers instead of functions for individual dropdowns, as it is better for scalability.

First thing, change this in CSS:

```
.mainsizer.open .dropdown-menus {
  display: block;
}
```

And in your JavaScript, do this:

```
$(function () {
  $("label").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".mainsizer").hasClass("open"))
      $(this).next(".mainsizer").toggleClass("open");
    else {
      $(".open").removeClass("open");
      $(this).next(".mainsizer").addClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

Ultimately, you should have this code:

```js
$(function () {
  $("label").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".mainsizer").hasClass("open"))
      $(this).next(".mainsizer").toggleClass("open");
    else {
      $(".open").removeClass("open");
      $(this).next(".mainsizer").addClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.outer-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  top: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.down-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 105%;
}
.down-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.down-nav {
  z-index: 1
  font-size: 105%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.down-nav:hover {
  color: white;
  border: solid 3px gray;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.down-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.caret_down {
  font-size: 30%;
}
.mainsizer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 164px;
}
.dropdown-menus {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 164px;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menus a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 8% 0px 15% 0%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 0%;
  text-indent: 4%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.dropdown-menus a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
.mainsizer.open .dropdown-menus {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="outer-bar">
  <ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-1" class="down-nav" onclick="Dropdown1()">Knives <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-1">
          <a href=/?search=M9%20Bayonet&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="m9_bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M9 Bayonet</a>
          <a href=/?search=Karambit&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="karambit" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:59px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Karambit</a>
          <a href=/?search=Bayonet&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:116px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bayonet</a>
          <a href=/?search=Butterfly%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="butterfly" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:170px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Butterfly Knife</a>
          <a href=/?search=Flip%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="flip" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:225px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Flip Knife</a>
          <a href=/?search=Falchion%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="falchion" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:280px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Falchion Knife</a>
          <a href=/?search=Gut%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="gut" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:334.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Gut Knife</a>
          <a href=/?search=Shadow%20Daggers&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="shadow" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:390px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Shadow Daggers</a>
          <a href=/?search=Huntsman%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="huntsman" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:444px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Huntsman Knife</a>
          <a href=/?search=Bowie%20Knife&type=weapon class="Text1"><label class="bowie" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:498.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bowie Knife</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-2" class="down-nav">Pistols <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-2">
          <a href=?search=Glock-18&type=weapon><label class="glock-18" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:9.5px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Glock-18</a>
          <a href=?search=USP-S&type=weapon><label class="usp-s" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:59px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>USP-S</a>
          <a href=?search=P2000&type=weapon><label class="p2k" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:106px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>P2000</a>
          <a href=?search=Five-Seven&type=weapon><label class="five-seven" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:157px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Five-SeveN</a>
          <a href=?search=Desert%20Eagle&type=weapon><label class="desert-eagle" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:207px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Desert Eagle</a>
          <a href=?search=Tec-9&type=weapon><label class="tec9" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:258px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Tec-9</a>
          <a href=?search=CZ75-Auto&type=weapon><label class="cz75" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:307px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>CZ75-Auto</a>
          <a href=?search=P250&type=weapon><label class="p250" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:357.5px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>P250</a>
          <a href=?search=Dual%20Berettas&type=weapon><label class="dual_berettas" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:407px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Dual Berettas</a>
          <a href=?search=R8%20Revolver&type=weapon><label class="r8_revolver" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:461.5px;left:4px;cursor:pointer;"></label>R8 Revolver</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-4" class="down-nav">SMGs <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-3">
          <a href=?search=P90&type=weapon><label class="p90" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>P90</a>
          <a href=?search=MAC-10&type=weapon><label class="mac10" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:61px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>MAC-10</a>
          <a href=?search=MP7&type=weapon><label class="mp7" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:111px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>MP7</a>
          <a href=?search=MP9&type=weapon><label class="mp9" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:161px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>MP9</a>
          <a href=?search=PP-Bizon&type=weapon><label class="pp-bizon" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:210px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>PP-Bizon</a>
          <a href=?search=UMP-45&type=weapon><label class="ump45" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:261.5px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>UMP-45</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-5" class="down-nav">Rifles <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-4">
          <a href=?search=AK-47&type=weapon><label class="ak47" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:9.5px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>AK-47</a>
          <a href=?search=Galil%20Ar&type=weapon><label class="galil_ar" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:61px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Galil AR</a>
          <a href=?search=SG%20553&type=weapon><label class="sg553" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:111px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>SG 553</a>
          <a href=?search=M4A4&type=weapon><label class="m4a4" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:161px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M4A4</a>
          <a href=?search=M4A1-S&type=weapon><label class="m4a1s" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:211.5px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M4A1-S</a>
          <a href=?search=AUG&type=weapon><label class="aug" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:261.5px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>AUG</a>
          <a href=?search=Famas&type=weapon><label class="famas" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:311.5px;left:8px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Famas</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-6" class="down-nav">Snipers <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-5">
          <a href=?search=AWP&type=weapon><label class="awp" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:9.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>AWP</a>
          <a href=?search=SSG%2008&type=weapon><label class="ssg08" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:61px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>SSG 08</a>
          <a href=?search=SCAR-20&type=weapon><label class="scar20" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:111px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>SCAR-20</a>
          <a href=?search=G3SG1&type=weapon><label class="g3sg1" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:161px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>G3SG1</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-6" class="down-nav">Heavy <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-6">
          <a href=?search=Nova&type=weapon><label class="nova" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:9.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Nova</a>
          <a href=?search=MAG-7&type=weapon><label class="mag-7" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:61px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>MAG-7</a>
          <a href=?search=XM1014&type=weapon><label class="xm1014" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:111px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>XM1014</a>
          <a href=?search=Sawed-Off&type=weapon><label class="sawed_off" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:161px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Sawed-Off</a>
          <a href=?search=Negev&type=weapon><label class="negev" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:211.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Negev</a>
          <a href=?search=M249&type=weapon><label class="m249" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:261.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M249</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label id="down-nav-7" class="down-nav">Others <b class="caret_down">&#9660;</b></label>
      <div class="mainsizer">
        <div class="dropdown-menus" id="dropdown-menu-7">
          <a href=?search=Keys&type=weapon><label class="keys" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:6px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Keys</a>
          <a href=?search=Cases&type=weapon><label class="cases" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:61px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Cases</a>
          <a href=?search=Passes&type=weapon><label class="passes" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:105.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Passes</a>
          <a href=?search=Capsules&type=weapon><label class="capsules" style="width:30px;height:23px;position:absolute;top:156.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Capsules</a>
          <a href=?search=Pins&type=weapon><label class="pins" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:207px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Pins</a>
          <a href=?search=Packages&type=weapon><label class="packages" style="width:30px;height:14px;position:absolute;top:264.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Packages</a>
          <a href=?search=Stickers&type=weapon><label class="stickers" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:308px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Stickers</a>
          <a href=?search=Music%20Kits&type=weapon><label class="music_kits" style="width:30px;height:34px;position:absolute;top:356.5px;left:13.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Music Kits</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Full Screen Output: http://output.jsbin.com/jeropupogu**

Comment: @ShellRox I have also provided a full screen preview... Once you click on the menu, if there are anything else open, that gets closed and then current menu will be opened. If the current menu is open, that's closed. This is the logic I am following, hope that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it would open menu, but when my main goal was to get menu closed when clicked outside of it. (Also i knew HTML checkbox solution, just  trying to fit website with Trident layout engine).

Comment: @ShellRox Clicking outside, you can use one solution what Bootstrap does. I have recently answered it. Lemme get you the link.

Comment: Yes sure, answer almost fixed my problem so, i hope there is compatiable way for javascript to detect outside click of menu.

Comment: @ShellRox http://jsbin.com/xoputuniru/1/edit?html,css,js,output Check this please. Now this is a complete fix.

Comment: it still doesn't close when clicking outside :(.

Comment: @ShellRox Did you try in the [JSBin output](http://output.jsbin.com/xoputuniru/1)? Works perfectly for me. Please check again.

Comment: Previous answer just solved my problem, apologies but i found it difficult to understand why it didn't work on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal, working (although not styled completely) version, using no JS, and very basic HTML and CSS. Should work in any browser.

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 5em;
}
.nav a {
  color: white;
  }
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
.nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  }
.nav ul li > ul {
  display: none;
  }
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  }
.down-nav {
  font-size: 105%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  border: solid .2em transparent;
}
.down-nav:hover {
  border: solid .2em gray;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 1em;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="down-nav">Knives <span>&#9660;</span>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="/?search=M9%20Bayonet&type=weapon">M9 Bayonet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Karambit&type=weapon">Karambit</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Bayonet&type=weapon">Bayonet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Butterfly%20Knife&type=weapon">Butterfly Knife</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Flip%20Knife&type=weapon">Flip Knife</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Falchion%20Knife&type=weapon">Falchion Knife</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Gut%20Knife&type=weapon">Gut Knife</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Shadow%20Daggers&type=weapon">Shadow Daggers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Huntsman%20Knife&type=weapon">Huntsman Knife</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?search=Bowie%20Knife&type=weapon">Bowie Knife</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="down-nav">Pistols <span>&#9660;</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/?search=Glock-18&type=weapon">Glock-18</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=USP-S&type=weapon">USP-S</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=P2000&type=weapon">P2000</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=Five-Seven&type=weapon">Five-SeveN</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=Desert%20Eagle&type=weapon">Desert Eagle</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=Tec-9&type=weapon">Tec-9</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=CZ75-Auto&type=weapon">CZ75-Auto</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=P250&type=weapon">P250</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=Dual%20Berettas&type=weapon">Dual Berettas</a></li>
          <li><a href="/?search=R8%20Revolver&type=weapon">R8 Revolver</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my main objective is not hover, i am trying to open menu when clicked.

Comment: Ah, then you would have to use a `<input type="checkbox">` instead. `:checked` should work in all the later incarnations of IE, so as long as you only need to support IE 9+, that should work just fine.